# using a template parameter within a template function

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, g++

I get an g++ compiler error (expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token) in exportFoo< ST >:

```
class FOO {
    ...
    template<typename DT, typename ST>
    void foo(...);
    ...
};

template<typename DT, typename ST>
void
FOO::doFoo(...)
{
    ...
    size_t memSize = 
        (dynamic_cast< FooImpl< DT > >(obj))->exportFoo< ST >(...);
    ...
}
```

If I replace "DT" by a valid and known data type there is no compiler error.
So I guess that the compiler doesn't interprete the generic data types DT and ST as valid parameters for the object cast "< DT > " and the function call within the function. By try and error I've prefixed the cast with `FooImpl<typename DT>` but it doesn't run. Does somebody has a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: `foo` vs `doFoo`, what is `FooImpl`, `exportFoo` ?

Comment: dynamic_cast< FooImpl< DT > >(obj))->template exportFoo< ST >(...);

Comment: somebody gives temporary the hint;-)